# i want to write a code which accepts int and makes a horizontal bar with the number of asterisks as of int

Tags: java

```java
import java.util.*;

public class assign {
    public static void main(String[]args){

        Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter first number between 1 to 30");
        int a = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter second number between 1 to 30");
        int b = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter third number between 1 to 30");
        int c = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter fourth number between 1 to 30");
        int d = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter fifth number between 1 to 30");
        int e = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.close();

        for(int i=0;i<a-1;i++);{
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
        for(int i=0;i<b-1;i++);{
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
        for(int i=0;i<c-1;i++);{
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
        for(int i=0;i<d-1;i++);{
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
        for(int i=0;i<e-1;i++);{
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    
}
```

[image]

the output gives only one asterisk per line instead of required the number of scanned quantity

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: There is a semicolon that makes the for loop useless `for(int i=0;i<a-1;i++);{` ==> `for(int i=0;i<a-1;i++){`

Comment: use a propre IDE like https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=windows, it'll tell you that with a nice `for statement has empty body`

Comment: i want the first line of asterisks to have the number of asterisks as entered in first line. same for all lines. so it is like a horizontal bar graph made by using the entered values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Fix

Remove the semicolon, and change the bound from `a-1` to `a` to have the good amount

```
for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    System.out.print("*");
}
```

---

#### Improve

With [`String.repeat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int))

```
System.out.println("*".repeat(a));
System.out.println("*".repeat(b));
System.out.println("*".repeat(c));
System.out.println("*".repeat(d));
System.out.println("*".repeat(e));
```